# Laravel 5.2 - Create Database table from a Controller

Tags: database, laravel, controller, schema

Apologies if this have been asked, but I don't seem to find the right answer.

I need to create a table in the DB from a Controller.

I was naive enough to believe the below would work:

```
    Schema::connection('mysql')->create('mytable_'.$id, function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Where `$id` is a dynamic value passed into the controller's function.

I've placed the below on the top:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
```

No luck - How can a DB table be created from the controller then? Any ideas?

Error:
[image]

**Solution**
As Ben Swinburne has said in the first comment, the `use Schema` was missing!

Comment: What happens? do you get an error? You'd need `use Schema` too in order to use the schema facade.

Comment: You are right... I was just missing use Schema... thank you very much.

Comment: Posted an answer so the question can be removed from unanswered lists.

Comment: Does `DB::select('your raw query here')` work also with other queries than select statements?

Comment: @ClaudioKing You should use `DB::statement()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the `Schema` facade.

Make sure you have `use Schema;` at the top of your file too.

Answer (score 1):

I think best approach will be creating a migration and running `php artisan migrate` command [from your controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code):

```
Artisan::call('migrate');
```

If you do not know how to create migrations from code using `stubs`, you can learn that from some well-written package. I've learned how to do that from [this package](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable).

Hope this will help

Comment: Some times you just need to create a table inside a controller. eg: I am importing some contacts, I wish to load that to a temp table, then delete it later. I obviously cant use a general purpose common table, since on a multi-user environment, more than one person may be using the "general purpose table"